# Change Variables from other Class

Tags: java, variables

If I have a Java Project with f.e 3 classes and think something happens in your first Class and now you want to change the value in the third Class how can you do that !? When I have my first Class where I make a reference to my second Class with something like

```
SecondClass mSecondClass =new SecondClass()
```

and then at least in the second class I create my 3rd class with

```
...=New ThirdClass()
```

If I have implemented a method in the second class like `setValue(int v)` I can change the value of the second Class from my first class and then do the same Form the second to the third Class but shouldn't be there a easier way ?

Comment: Unless they are static variables, you don't change values in classes, you change values in instances of classes.

Comment: But if I declare a Variable in my Class f.e public int mValue=0; How can I acces this variable from another class ?

Comment: Well, you can't access the variable from anywhere until you create an instance of the class.  (`new` creates an instance.)

Comment: Okay,that's what I do. I have my first class where I create a Instance of my second class  and then in the second class I create the Instance of my third class. But how can I get the instance of my third class in my first class ?

Comment: And thanks Sotirios for editing my Question to make it better to read :)

Comment: @ConstantinMarcel, you're having a misunderstanding about how objects and classes work. You can create objects of any class (if accessible) inside any class of your project. You can use instance or static members too. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there can be an easy way, to directly change the value of `ThirdClass` object from your `FirstClass`. Why are you even trying to communicate through `SecondClass`? Did you mean to use [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming))? That is not how encapsulation works in Object-oriented programming. Encapsulation is to create an abstraction of data from all other classes, not just one (in your case `FirstClass`). You can provide these interfaces (not those `interface`, but these functions `setValue`) inside your `ThirdClass` class and then let `FirstClass` objects also use these functions. You can use your classes inside your package, you knew that didn't you?

Secondly, as already mentioned changing the values of the variables depends on what variables you want to change.

1. Static variables
2. Instance variables

If you're trying to change a static variable, then create a new instance and update the value, something like this

```
ThirdClass three = new ThirdClass();
three.setValue(0); // int v
```

Otherwise, if that is a static field (variable),

ThirdClass.Value = 0; // public int Value; "No encapsulation" BAD!

If you're having encapsulation on then just simply call the (*static*) function inside your Class as,

```
ThirdClass.setValue(0); // int v
// it also assume you're having
public static void setValue(int v) { /* code here */ }
```

This way, you update your values. You might consider giving "[Understanding class members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)" a look, it would help you in understanding how members are treated.

Comment: Yeah,If I could I would skip second class and comunicate from class1 directly to class3 . The thing is that I don't have an instance of my third class in my first class. But,can I crate an Instance of my 3.class in my first and second class too ? That would solve theissue; would this mean I have my 3.object (my 3.Class and I can acces this object from my first and second class ? Or do I create two objekts when I create two references ? Then the reference in class1 wouldn't acces the same objekt like the reference in class 2 what i don't want .

Comment: Wait, relax! Just create the instance of the object in your own class; which-so-ever class. There is no limit on instances, just make sure memory has enough space to hold them all. Keep it simple please.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to look at the whole system and control it all at once. The point of object oriented programming is to hide away the details of how your 3rd class might need to do something caused by your 1st one.

There must be a reason these classes link to each other in the first place. Let's say that the first class is where all things start. That class should have a clear set of things which it lets its users ask from it, and it should implement those things by modifying its internal values and asking any objects inside of it to do things to help it. Keep that way of thinking going down the chain, and it will make more sense.

Your commenters are right. You need to distinguish between a class - a bunch of code defining how an object can work - and objects - a specific thing at runtime that's getting and sending messages.

In Java object messages are really function calls and we kind of know that there's a bit of procedural-like flowing going on behind the scenes. Ignore that.

Hope this helps.

In short - think about delegation of responsibility to object and a way of programming where things make requests to objects that can help.

As a more specific answer here's how some objects might interact.

```
class Train {
    private Engine engine;
    private Whistle whistle;

    public Train() {
        // these components are part of the train and so
        // are constructed when it's constructed
        engine = new Engine();
        whistle = new Whistle();
    }

    public void go() {
        whistle.toot();
        engine.start();
    }
}


class Driver {
    private Train train;
    private IPod iPod;

    public Driver(IPod iPod, Train train) {
        // the driver may be given any ipod
        // and any train to drive
        this.iPod = iPod;
        this.train = train; 
    }

    public void drive() {
        iPod.startMusic();
        train.go();
    }
}

// main method
IPod iPod = new IPodNano();
Train train = new Train();

Driver driver = new Driver(iPod, train);
driver.drive();
```

Now you see how delegation of responsibility can exist in a network of connected objects which are linked together at run time in a couple of different ways.

Comment: what you mentioned is exactly a problem of mine. The lanquage I started with was C,and there you have "void main()" where I can put everything I want into and the programm will follow exactly this funktion. Java doesn't do that,and that's what I have to come up with since I red the first Java tutorial . Alltough it's easy to think of your Program acting like real-world objects that isn't what the computer does,the computer works "more like C" than like java. But I'm trying to get used to it !

Comment: Okay,after a littlebit of coding the following turned out for me. If I create a Instance with f.e  "Class3 mClass3=new Class3() " I'l get a new "self-acting" objekt . And that will always happen when you write this code, so Creating a Instance of Class3 in Class1 AND Class2 will not solve the Issue,as they don't refer on the same Object (allthough these Created Objekts are acting the same way )- for explanation one of these would be named "Self-Acting objekt nr.1" and the other one "Self-acting objekt nr.2"

Comment: So I don't know if there is a way to get a reference to an already existing Objekt in a class where this objekt wasn't created, but if there is no way I'l have to change the way the classes are interacting between each other (f.e if I create my Instance of class1 and class3 in class2 )

Comment: You can pass a reference to an object into the constructor. This means another object can reference it too.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the link "understanding class members" I've finally understood why you can write "static" before your Variables or methods and it solves my Problem,too. Thanks everyone for your help !

Comment: If static solves your problem, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: What am I doing wrong when I use static ? Because it works for me ! To change the value of a static variable I write something like "Class3.setValue(x)" and I can write it everywhere and don't have to care about if I have an instance of the class in the class where I change the Value or not . To be exactely, what confused me is I red somewhere "to change the value you have to write 'violatitle' " before the variable.

Comment: Statics are like global variables - if you're hacking your way into the static state of a class to link things together, then you're missing the point. Volatile is used when there's multi-threading. To be honest, Constantin, you probably need to go ahead and read a primer for Java and OO, because this isn't the best way to learn some of the real basics. However, in the spirit of explanation, see the edit to my answer above.